# iOS swift remove UITableView Cell separator space

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i am trying to remove the tableView separator, i do that by setting the separator style to none, this removes the separator but leaves the space between the cells.

My question is how do i remove that space between the cells?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `awakeFromNib` function setting `UITableViewCell` options to `UIEdgeInsetsZero` should work

```
  self.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
  self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

Comment: if you can approve the answer the other can see it's working, happy coding Swift!

Comment: yes will do that just waiting for stackoverflow to let me approve the answer

Answer (score -2):

I do it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
    // remove the spaces on the cell separators
    if (cell.respondsToSelector("setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:")) {
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    }
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    if(cell.respondsToSelector("setLayoutMargins:")){            
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
```