# UITableview separator not hiding for iOS9

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios9

I have implemented `UITableView` with coding. I have also set `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`. It is hiding for iOS8 and below but not hiding with iOS9 Beta.

Comment: possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145103/ios-swift-remove-uitableview-cell-separator-space/31145169#31145169

Comment: Its not duplicate of mentioned question. The result I want to achieve is far different than the result achieved in that question.

Comment: Check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25877725/1268426

Comment: I DONT WANT TO CHANGE THE INSET OF SEPARATOR. I WANT TO HIDE IT.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. File a radar at bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: Filed a radar, 21933047: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5027942857965568

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Please set the separator style to None in layoutSubviews method.

When constraints-based layout is used the base implementation applies the constraints-based layout and setting separatorStyle to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone in this method will hide the separator for you.

Comment: doing this in viewDidLayoutSubviews (in my view controller) worked as well.

Comment: If you are creating a table in a uiview you would want to set this in the DrawRect property of the view.

Answer (score 5):

From my investigations, it's not iOS 9 at fault, but Xcode 7.0 beta 4.

If I build the app using Xcode 7.0 beta 4, then the cell separators are shown even when set to None in Interface Builder. If I build the same code with Xcode 6.4 or 7.0 beta 3, the separators are not shown.

You can explicitly call this in your ViewController as a workaround:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

(I guess `ibtool` may be at fault)

Comment: In My case I am loading UITableview from the Code building with xcode 6.4 still I am getting this issue.

Comment: I get the problem in my current projet although I build a tableView and its properties programmatically. Therefore ibtool might be at fault, but he's not the only guilty actor :)

Comment: Perfect, when I update to final Xcode version I get fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I'm also facing the same issue. My workaround was just to set

`tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()`.

Answer (score 3):

Solution from [apple developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12387) that worked for me:

*You can remove the separators by set UITableViewCellSeparatorNone before every reloadData method (ios 9.1). I don't know why, but UITableView resets separatorStyle and separatorColor every tyme after the reloadData method is called.*

Comment: Do you mean after or in each reloadData call?  I had a similar experience where I had to add additional calls to set the separator and the background colors to get tables to appear correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the separator style to `.None` didn't work for me, so I used the edge insets as a hack workaround

```
self.tableView.separatorInset.left = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
```

Comment: YESSSSS. The only solution that also works when there are not enough cells to fill the tableview.

Answer (score 2):

Below code worked for me,

```
  override func layoutSubviews() {
     super.layoutSubviews()
     tableView.separatorStyle = .none 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, worked fine on iOS 8 but show the separator in iOS9. I was setting the separator style to none already. The following resolved it for me

```
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;
    }
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, cell.bounds.size.width);
    if([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }
```

This basically squash the separator using the inset.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is quite annoying. And here is my solution:

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    if self.superview != nil {
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .None
    }
}
```

Set the separatorStyle again when view is added to its superview.

Answer (score 0):

```
myTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

for Swift

```
myTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
```

in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method will hide white lines in iOS 9 and later.